# Where is the Magento 1.9 developer documentation?

Tags: documentation

The only good/bonafide documentation I can find is here:

[https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-1.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20200219112633/https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-1.html)

but in that documentation, it even states that there's much more to learn. Is there any other good documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the latest archived repo:
https://github.com/magento/devdocs-m1

Final tagged release:
https://github.com/magento/devdocs/releases/tag/1.x-eos

As well as the link announcing the removal of the m1 dev docs: https://github.com/magento/devdocs/pull/7452

Answer (score 0):

Please try this: https://github.com/magento/devdocs
There are so many documents and blogs available for Magento1, please find as per. Your need.

Comment: It looks like that's magento 2. What about magento 1?

Answer (score -1):

May be this will help you some:

https://www.openmage.org/

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-1.html

https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/Resources/archive/magento_community_edition_user_guide_v.1.9.pdf

https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html

Comment: I listed your first link in my OP. The other two appear to be for non-developers. Know of any other magento 1 developer docs?

Comment: May be this will help you: https://docs.swissuplabs.com/m1/dev/
Is there any specific topic you are looking for? if not then I'll suggest you for E-books : https://whatpixel.com/best-magento-books/